# C++ calculator displays and extra 0 in the end

Tags: c++, calculator

I am having this problem with my calculator I made. See, when I type in a calculation it always adds a 0 to the end. I don't know how to fix this do you have any ideas?

Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void Input(float &x, float &y);

float a = 1.0, b = 1.0, result;
char op;

int main() {

    cout << "Welcome to Foxy's calculator" << endl;
    cout << "----------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "Please input a calculation operation (eg. 1+1): ";
    cin >> a >> op >> b;

    Input(a, b);

    cout << result << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}


void Input (float &x, float &y) {

    a = x;
    b = y;

    switch (op)
    {
    case '+':
        cout << x + y;
        break;

    case '-':
        cout << x - y;
        break;

    case '*':
        cout << x*y;
        break;

    case '/':
        cout << x / y;
        break;

    default:
        cout << "Error! Operator is not correct" << endl;
        cout << "Please input your calculation with a proper operator: ";
        cin >> a >> op >> b;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`result` is a global static variable that gets zero - initialized and is never changed. So `cout << result << endl;` will always print "0". To fix this you should make `a`, `b`, `result` and `op` local to `main` (global variables are bad), pass `a`, `b` and`op` to calculating function and store returned calculation result in `result`. It will look something like this:

```
float result = Input(a, b, op);
cout << result << endl;
```

Answer (score 3):

You call `cout << result << endl;` in the caller. and `result` is always 0. This is because it is never explicitly set to anything and the C++ compiler kindly zero-initialises it since it's at global scope.

In such instances, your line by line debugger is your best friend. The fact that you've mashed up your 1) input, 2) calculation, and 3) output stages is not helping: ideally they should all be separate parts of your program.

Comment: Since `result` is in global scope - it is zero-initialized.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius: Oops.

Comment: All these comments are saying the same :/ but they work!

Comment: @Foxy885: Yes, Stack Overflow works best when there are a selection of answers to pick from. But I prefer VTT's answer, and it was correct first time unlike mine, which had a serious technical error.

Answer (score 1):

Remove cout << result << endl;

Comment: Doing this made the "press enter to continue" button go to the same line but after that I tried only removing the "result" and that worked. Thx.